# "bent" meaning in "the contemptuous look he bent upon Harry"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> He [Kreacher, a house elf] was still wearing the filthy rag in which they had first met him, and the contemptuous look he ***bent*** upon Harry showed that his attitude to his change of ownership had altered no more than his outfit.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I don't understand the use of "bent" in this context. I've looked up 'bend' in [this dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bend).  But it seems that no definition could fit in my view. What's 'bend' supposed to mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that meaning 4 in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bend) fits the usage.

> **bend<sup>1</sup>**
>   VERB
>
> **4** Direct (one's attention or energies) to a task.
>
> *He bent his thoughts to see if he could pick up on Chanet's thoughts.*
>   *For several years he bent his efforts to the building of a railroad through the County.*
>   *When his choice was made he bent his attention to the table.*

So the sentence means that Kreacher gave Harry an intense and disrespectful look.

Comment: You can bend your gaze on someone.